# Analyze similarities in model data using Elasticsearch and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, data-analysis, searchkick

I would like to use Elasticsearch to analyze data and display it to the user.

When a user views a record for a model, I want to display a list of 'similar' records in the database for that model, and the percentage of similarity. This would match against every field on the model.

I am aware that with the Searchkick gem I can use a command to find similar records:

```
product = Product.first
product.similar(fields: ["name"], where: {size: "12 oz"})
```

I would like to take this further and compare entire records (and eventually associations).

Is this feasible with Elasticsearch / Searchkick in Rails, or should I use another method to analyze the data?

Comment: I'm trying to write a complete answer but I miss some info. What do you mean when you say that you'd like to compare associations? When you mention a model record do you just mean a standard Elasticsearch document?

Comment: Thanks for the response. For now I am willing to ignore the associations and focus on a standard Elasticsearch document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature built exactly for this purpose in Elasticsearch called `more_like_this`. The documentation for the [mlt](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query goes into great details about how you can achieve exactly what you want to do.

The content you provide to the `like` field will be analyzed and the most relevant terms for each field will be used to retrieve documents with as many of those relevant terms. If you have all your records stored in Elasticsearch, you can use the [Multi GET syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) to specify a document already in your index as content of the `like` field like this:

```
    "like" : [
      {
        "_index" : "model",
        "_type" : "model",
        "_id" : "1"
      }
    ]
```

Remember that you cannot use index aliases when using this syntax (so you'll have to do a document lookup first if you are not sure which index your document is currently residing in).

If you don't specify the `fields` field, all fields in the source document will be used. My suggestion to avoid bad surprises, is to always specify the list of `fields` you want your similar documents to match.

If you have non-textual fields that you want to match perfectly with the source document, you might want to consider using a [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query, programmatically creating the `filter` section to limit documents returned by the `mlt` query to only a filtered subset of your entire index.

You can build these queries in Searchkick using the [advanced search](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search) feature, manually specifying the body of search requests.

Comment: Thanks @micpalmia . Learned something from your answer. There is lot of extra work avoided by using elastic search that you likely need anyway compared to implementing yet new environment for data warehouse based machine learning. Only thing left to figure out  is how do I personalise this based on individual user actions vs general search results?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on using [More Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).  This is the query produced by `product.similar()`.  It operates only on text fields. If you also want to compare numeric or date fields, you'll have to incorporate these rules into a [scoring script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) to do what you're asking.

Comment: Fundamentally you have to define what "similar" means in the context of what you're trying to do.  You can do that in Elasticsearch, Python or in any language that lets you iterate over your entire resultset.  Since you're not *excluding* any docs from consideration, there's no benefit of using index structures to speed things up.  It's a table-scan no matter how you slice it.